# Draw new line in Trading View by using Pine Script

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

Can anyone explain line no. 3 and 4 in this code?

```
1 //@version=4
2 study("array.new_line example",overlay = true)

3 plot(bar_index)
4 line.new(bar_index-1, close[1], bar_index, close,width =2)
```

I expected the line from start. Because bar indexing starts from 0 on the first historical bar. But its showing as different. why?

```
line.new(bar_index-1, close[1], bar_index, close,width =2)
```

I have read the documentation. But still not get the answer.

[https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_line{dot}new](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_line%7Bdot%7Dnew)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`study()`, `indicator()` and `strategy()` have an argument called `max_lines_count`. This determines the number of last line drawings displayed. By default it is set to `50`.

Once you have more lines, it will start deleting the old ones to create the new ones. You can set it to `500` and you will see all the lines on your chart (`BANKNIFTY @1M`).